# parallax Effext Not Working

Tags: html, css, parallax

I want an image to fit a container element but my code is only showing half of the image, without the desired parallax effect. Can anyone explain why it isn't displaying the full image?

```
<header>
    <div class="top_nav">

    </div>
</header>
    <div class="container">
    <div id="short-des">

</div>
</div>
<div class=details>
</div>

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.top_nav{
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: absolute;
}

.container{
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url("cover.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}

.details{
    height: 638px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#00e5de;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```css
.section1 {
  background: url(http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/galaxy-wallpapers-10.jpg) no-repeat fixed center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.section2 {
  background: url(https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1462121457351-9fb0f5622b72) no-repeat fixed center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.section3 {
  background: url(https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1465420961937-e0eba4dda519) no-repeat fixed center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section1"></div>
<div class="section2"></div>
<div class="section3"></div>
```